# type noRows struct{} var _ Result = noRows{}

Tags: go

```
type noRows struct{}

var _ Result = noRows{}
```

My question is why initialize a variable but discard it immediately？

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what does a underscore and interface name after keyword var in golang mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13194272/what-does-a-underscore-and-interface-name-after-keyword-var-in-golang-mean)

Answer (score 7):

The blank identifier has many possible uses, but its main purpose is to allow discarding returns from functions that have multiple returns:

```
// We only care about the rune and possible error, not its length
r, _, err := buf.ReadRune()
```

There are some other fun, but sometimes hackish, uses.

Mark an import or local variable as "used" so that the compiler won't issue an error:

```
import "fmt"

var _ = fmt.Println // now fmt is used and the compiler won't complain

func main() {
    var x int
    _ = x // now x is used and the compiler won't complain
}
```

Make sure a type implements an interface at compile time:

```
var _ InterfaceType = Type{} // or new(Type), or whatever
```

Ensure that a constant lies within a certain range at compile time:

```
// Ensure constVal <= 10
const _ uint = 10 - constVal
// Ensure constVal >= 1 (constVal > UINT_MAX + 1 is also an error)
const _ uint = -1 + constVal
```

Ensure a function parameter is unused:

```
// This could be useful if somebody wants a value of type
// func(int, int) int
// but you don't want the second parameter.
func identity(x, _ int) int { return x }
```

Answer (score 3):

Some people use a line like as an interface check. This line ensures that the type `noRows` implements the `Result` interface. If it doesn't you will get a compiler error.

I believe checks like that are unnecessary. Normally any type of test involving that type will tell you when a type does not satisfy and important interface. In very rare cases, you can add a conversion test to your unit tests.